# Does naming your character “Chara” change anything in the Genocide Route?

Tags: undertale

I have barely picked up the game and I have gone through the *TRUE Pacifist* ending of Undertale and am kind of deep into the *Genocide Route* already.  So I would like to know if anything changes if you name the human “Chara”.  I tried Google, but that didn’t have anything I could work with.

Answer (score 3):

The only change is that you receive unique text when asked to confirm the name 'Chara' in the name selection menu. This does not affect gameplay on any route. [Source is the Undertale Wiki page.](https://undertale.fandom.com/wiki/Names)

There is only one name that changes gameplay after confirming name selection, but with this name, a Genocide route is not possible. It is

> Frisk